# Report Viewer 2010 TextBox Alignment Issue in Windows Form

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, reportviewer

I wonder why there's no 'justify' option in Report Viewer 2010. Available options are only Align Left, Center, and Align Right. I'm trying to figure out how to align the text box (justify) but I could not find any clues.

[image]

I see that Report Viewer also supports HTML rendering. I have tried that too using HTML text-align=justify, but it doesn't work. As well as TextBox, I have also tested using Tablix but no luck. I hope someone can help me figure this out.

FYI, I'm using Visual Studio 2010 SP1 with Report Viewer 2010 (.NET 4)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I concerned *justify* is not supported by Microsoft Report Viewer. Some time ago we had to choose Crystal Reports to have *justify* possibility.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but are you sure that the latest version of Crystal Reports has this feature? I don't see it in my Visual Studio 2010 IDE. I need an official clarification on this.

Comment: All Crystal Reports version have this feature. Crystal Report has to be separatelly installed for VS 2010. It is available to download [here](http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/default.asp)

Comment: Well, I have installed CR separately. However, I have to set the properties of the Text Object itself (not available at the toolbar) to enable justify (HorAlignment), which is not available in Report Viewer. Now, everything is clear that I must migrate to Crystal Report just for this small issue.